# OSError when reading image files using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

When trying to follow the example [posted here](http://learningtensorflow.com/lesson3/).  The code segment is the same as given in the example

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
filename = "/home/MarshOrchid.jpg"
image = mpimg.imread(filename)

# Print out its shape
print(image.shape)
```

Running the code gives the following error message. What could be the underlying cause?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test2.py", line 5, in <module>
   image = mpimg.imread(filename)
File "/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.1-py3.4-linux-   x86_64.egg/matplotlib/image.py", line 1304, in imread
im = pilread(fname)
File "/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.1-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/image.py", line 1283, in pilread
return pil_to_array(image)
File "/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.1-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/image.py", line 1400, in pil_to_array
x = toarray(im)
File "/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.1-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/image.py", line 1383, in toarray
x_str = im.tobytes('raw', im.mode)
File "/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Pillow-3.2.0-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/PIL/Image.py", line 678, in tobytes
File "/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Pillow-3.2.0-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 235, in load
File "/tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Pillow-3.2.0-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 59, in raise_ioerror
OSError: broken data stream when reading image file
```

Comment: Hrm this works for me -- on a Windows PC though.

Comment: What version of python are you using, also have you tried using a full file path?  I also had no issues on windows 10, py 3.5.2